# FireBase Phone Authentifiation

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication, one-time-password

So basically I implemented the phone authentification method, it is working fine and I receive the OTP on my phone everytime. but the problem is I can't extract the code from the OnCodeSent method

```
 public void onCodeSent(@NonNull String verificationId,
                       @NonNull PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken token) {
    // The SMS verification code has been sent to the provided phone number, we
    // now need to ask the user to enter the code and then construct a credential
    // by combining the code with a verification ID.
    Log.d(TAG, "onCodeSent:" + verificationId);

    // Save verification ID and resending token so we can use them later
    mVerificationId = verificationId;
    mResendToken = token;
}
```

When i Try to display the VerficationId, it displays a random string like AhfjnVDscqQHBFEFvCHdBVQHVQJNCvcHFBhbHBC instead of the OTP i received (523410). How do I fix this?

Comment: Yes that how it works. you can't display the code from the app. when the code is sent you get the verificationID and then you authenticate the user with the verificationId and the code imputed. if there are the same it will verify the user but if not it won't

Comment: the problem is whenim trying to verifiy the code , I have to test if VerificationId = OTP_Received .
That doesn't work because the app compares the OTP (523410) to that random String (AhfjnVDscqQHBFEFvCHdBVQHVQJNCvcHFBhbHBC)

Comment: sorry but you don't do the verification by your self. `PhoneAuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(verificationId, code);` when you get the code use the verificationId and the code gotten from the user, use the above method to get their crdentials.

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth#java_4 follow this link while I try to send you a complete break down in the answers

Comment: if I use the PhoneAuthCredential method, how can i make my app verify the codes match without logging in, I want to know exactly how to do it. I want to verify the codes in OTP_Receied and VerficationId match and display a Toast if true.
can someone send me the code

Comment: it does it on it's own. you just have to parse the code gotten from the user and it will check it on it's own

Answer (score 0):

start with this and the callback in is declared elsewhere in your code.

create a public string called verification ID

```
    PhoneAuthOptions options = 
  PhoneAuthOptions.newBuilder(mAuth) 
      .setPhoneNumber(phoneNumber)       // Phone number to verify
      .setTimeout(60L, TimeUnit.SECONDS) // Timeout and unit
      .setActivity(this)                 // Activity (for callback binding)
      .setCallbacks(mCallbacks)          // OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks
      .build();
  PhoneAuthProvider.verifyPhoneNumber(options);

    


mCallbacks = new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {

    @Override
    public void onVerificationCompleted(PhoneAuthCredential credential) {
        // This callback will be invoked in two situations:
        // 1 - Instant verification. In some cases the phone number can be instantly
        //     verified without needing to send or enter a verification code.
        // 2 - Auto-retrieval. On some devices Google Play services can automatically
        //     detect the incoming verification SMS and perform verification without
        //     user action.
        Log.d(TAG, "onVerificationCompleted:" + credential);
    }

    @Override
    public void onVerificationFailed(FirebaseException e) {
        // This callback is invoked in an invalid request for verification is made,
        // for instance if the the phone number format is not valid.
        Log.w(TAG, "onVerificationFailed", e);

        if (e instanceof FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException) {
            // Invalid request
        } else if (e `instanceof` FirebaseTooManyRequestsException) {
            // The SMS quota for the project has been exceeded
        }

        // Show a message and update the UI
    }

    @Override
    public void onCodeSent(@NonNull String verificationId,
                           @NonNull PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken token) {
        // The SMS verification code has been sent to the provided phone number, we
        // now need to ask the user to enter the code and then construct a credential
        // by combining the code with a verification ID.
        Log.d(TAG, "onCodeSent:" + verificationId);

        // Save verification ID and resending token so we can use them later
        mResendToken = token;
        signInCurrentUser(verificationId)
     }
    };
public void signInCurrentUser(String verificationId) {
    
        PhoneAuthCredential authCredential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(verificationId, getCode());
        signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(authCredential);
    
}

private void signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(PhoneAuthCredential credential) {
mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
        .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                    Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:success");

                    FirebaseUser user = task.getResult().getUser();
                    // Update UI
                } else {
                    // Sign in failed, display a message and update the UI
                    Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential:failure", task.getException());
                    if (task.getException() instanceof FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException) {
                        // The verification code entered was invalid
                    }
                }
            }
        });
   }
```

the get code method gets the user input